# Why can I access some shared folder and not others?

Tags: windows-7, permissions, file-sharing, windows-networking

I have four hard drives on my server running windows 7. Upon installing the operating system I set sharing permissions on all of them, yet when I browse the computer under "Network" on another computer, two of the drives work fine, but the other two give an error:

> "Windows cannot access \\server\f.
>   You do not have permission to access \\server\f. Contact your network administrator to request access."

On the server, if I right click one of the drives -> Share with -> Advanced sharing... and click the 'Advanced Sharing' button, 'Share this folder' is checked, user limit is 20 and if I click 'Permissions' the group 'Everyone' has 'Full Control' set to Allow. This is identical for all drives I'm trying to share.

Also, the denial of access is the same on all 3 computers I've tried to connect with (win8, win7, ubuntu 13)

Are there some settings I don't know about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem isn't about sharing though, I think it is about permissions. There are 2 places to set permissions (or so it appears - I don't understand the differences or why it can be set in 2 places but I'm sure there is a mad reason).

Right click the drive and keep the sharing as is but click on the security tab. In here, click edit, add "everyone" with full control.

[image: add everyone to permissions list]

Comment: huh... I would've thought that was just for local users... adding 'everyone' to the two drives worked, although maybe not the best idea for more sensitive environments. Someday when I'm not half asleep I shall delve deeper. Thanks man :)

Comment: Pleasure, and I agree with your comment about "everyone" (I did it for 2 reasons, 1 you already mention it in OP but I normally set it up as everyone initially, just to make sure I can get in, then I change it to what I need; it makes troubleshooting easier)

Comment: true, I DID say 'everyone' in my op lol

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem where I could share most folders, but not a certain one. It appears that when you share a folder the 'normal' security settings change, and Windows 10 deletes the permissions for "Authenticated Users".

My solution was to add "Authenticated users" to Folder Properties -- Security -- Change Permissions -- Add and then fill in "Authenticated users" and click OK!